# How to rotate UIBezierPath around center of its own bounds?

Tags: rotation, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cgaffinetransform

Lets say we have a UIBezierPath... the bounds of which are perfectly square... like this:

```
func getExponentPath(rotate180: Bool) -> UIBezierPath {

    // establish unit of measure (grid) based on this containing view's bounds... (not to be confused with this bezierpath's bounds)

    let G = bounds.width / 5

    let exponentPath = UIBezierPath()

    let sstartPoint = CGPoint(x:(3.8)*G,y:(1.2)*G)
    exponentPath.move(to: sstartPoint)
    exponentPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:(5)*G,y:(1.2)*G))
    exponentPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:(4.4)*G,y:(0.2)*G))
    exponentPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:(5)*G,y:(0.2)*G))
    exponentPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:(5)*G,y:(0)*G))
    exponentPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:(3.8)*G,y:(0)*G))
    exponentPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:(3.8)*G,y:(0.2)*G))
    exponentPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:(4.4)*G,y:(0.2)*G))
    exponentPath.addLine(to: sstartPoint)

    exponentPath.close()

    // this does not work:
    // if rotate180 { exponentPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)) }

    return exponentPath

}
```

If rotated, this bezierpath still needs to occupy the exact same area within its containing view.

I can only presume this does not work because there's some problem with the center of rotation not being what I intend... although I get the same (wrong) result even when saying "rotate by 0."

So how can the path be rotated around it's own center point?

It seems like there should be a simple linear algebra matrix multiplication type thingy that could be applied to the set of points. =T

Comment: Unclear what result you want. You are drawing way over at the top right corner of the "bounds". So where do you want the rotated shape to go? And why are you making such a tiny shape for such a big "bounds"?

Comment: it's gotta go in the same spot.  i think i might be answering my own question here shortly. derp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the rotation. To draw the same shape upside down, just flip it:

```
        exponentPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1))
        exponentPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: G))
```

Comment: appreciate that!  That answers the question.  I'm still interested in how to rotate a path arbitrarily on its own center... like if the function were getPath(rotate degrees: Int)... but for another day.

Comment: The problem is, where's the "center" for this shape? You see, what you're doing seems very weird to me. What I would do is draw the shape at 0,0 and then let the user (e.g. when you draw the actual image) move it into any desired location. At that point, rotating as you place it is trivial. But you are making the bezier path do all the work, which seems an odd way to draw. Your comment about the bezier path itself having "bounds" seems to me to expose the issue quite nicely.

Comment: I think the answer to the question you actually asked is: move the path so that its center is at the origin; rotate it; and move path back again. Like this: `exponentPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -4.4*G, y: -0.5*G)); exponentPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)); exponentPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 4.4*G, y: 0.5*G))`

Comment: But you see, it's all a bit skanky because of the question "where's the center".

Comment: Well I assumed since the path is known to be perfectly square, that the center is ( path.bounds.width/2 , path.bounds.height/2 ).  Thanks for extra info I'll play with that.

Comment: But you see there is no such thing as the bounds of a path, as I keep trying to say (I guess I'm not saying it clearly enough).

Comment: Well the reason I thought there was such a thing was that I said print("viewbounds: \(bounds.width) pathbounds: \(path.bounds.width)") ... and it printed what i expected... two different values, the second being much smaller.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's the bounding rectangle around the path.

Comment: Ya so it wouldn't work if it was a pesky shape like a triangle... but it this case it does!

Answer (score 4):

```
extension UIBezierPath
{
    func rotateAroundCenter(angle: CGFloat)
    {
        let center = self.bounds.getCenter()
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: center.x, y: center.y)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: angle)
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: -center.x, y: -center.y)
        self.apply(transform)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So in case anyone else is trying to rotate a UIBezierPath on the center of it's own bounding rectangle... this is the actual working solution arrived at with help from previous answers/comments:

```
func getExponentPath(rotationAngle: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

    // ...

    let x_translation = -( (bounds.width) - ( exponentPath.bounds.width/2) )
    let y_translation = -exponentPath.bounds.height/2

    exponentPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: x_translation, y: y_translation))
    exponentPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle))
    exponentPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -x_translation, y: -y_translation))

    // ...

}
```